# What Does the # mean in this ColdFusion Statement?

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to understand coldfusion better just to solve a minor problem. But for the life of me I cannot find what this means

```
<cfoutput query="manufactureList">#manufacturer_name#</cfoutput>
```

I know this is referencing a query named manfatureList, but was is #manufacturer_name# is that a variable?

Answer (score 7):

What you have is a poorly written code block.

To answer your question, anything inside the hashes is a ColdFusion variable. You need to use the hashes when you intend to output the value.

The problem with this statement you posted is that the developer left you to assume that manufacturer_name is part of the manufactureList query, which might be safe to assume but a terrible coding practice. You should always scope all variables for two reasons:

1. Readability and maintainability. Had they done this you probably would not have had to post a question here.
2. Scoping variables means that ColdFusion does not have to traverse the various scopes out there to figure out what scope this variable lives in. This leads to performance gains in your application. With some scopes, not scoping the call to the variable would mean that your code would fail to find it. Not so with query variables here, but for variables inside other structures that would happen.

Answer (score 3):

The #manufacturer_name# means that the value will be generated when the query is run. In your query you probably have a field called manufacturer_name.

By placing the manufacturer_name in the # sign it means that this field will be populated with the value from your query.

Here is an example:

```
<cfquery name="qEmployee" datasource="cfdocexamples">  
 SELECT Emp_ID, FirstName, LastName, Salary FROM EMPLOYEE  
</cfquery>  
      <table bgcolor="CadetBlue" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
     <tr bgcolor="DarkCyan">  
         <td><b>Emp ID</b></td>  
         <td><b>First Name</b></td>  
         <td><b>Last Name</b></td>  
         <td><b>Salary</b></td>  
        </tr>  
     <cfoutput query="qEmployee">  
            <tr>  
                <td>#Emp_ID#</td>  
                <td>#FirstName#</td>  
                <td>#LastName#</td>  
                <td>#Salary#</td>  
            </tr>  
        </cfoutput>  
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

string enclosed in # symbols do denote variables, in this case this is referring to a column name in the query "manufacurelist"

Answer (score 1):

Also, it's best practice to prepend the query name onto any columns from that query (and in fact do this with all variables, put them in their appropriate scope).

As well as making your code more efficient, it also makes life easier for the developer in the long run when you're trying to work out where a particular variable came from.

e.g. do this instead:

```
<cfoutput query="manufactureList">#manufactureList.manufacturer_name#</cfoutput>
```